# How to add js functions to elements that are only shown when the element before is on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

This is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t9aAf/

The task is to click on an item in the menu, so that the input field is filled with the selected value.
But it does not work.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="text">

  <div class="hints-menu">
    <span class="hints-title"><span>Title 1</span></span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 1</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 2</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 3</span>
    <span class="hints-title"><span>Title 2</span></span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 4</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 5</span>
    <span class="hints-title"><span>Title 3</span></span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 6</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 7</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 8</span>
    <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 9</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 260px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
input {
    width: 252px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;

    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input:focus + .hints-menu {
    display: block;
}
.hints-menu {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 240px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;

    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.hints-menu:before,
.hints-menu:after {
     bottom: 100%;
     left: 83%;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: "";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
}
.hints-menu:before {
     border-color: transparent;
     border-bottom-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 9px;
     margin-left: -9px;
}
.hints-menu:after {
     border-color: transparent;
     border-bottom-color: #fff;
     border-width: 8px;
     margin-left: -8px;
}
.hints-title,
.hint {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #555;
}
.hints-title {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
.hints-title span {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10%;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.hint {
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hint:hover {
    color: #6fa024;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click",".hint",function(){
            alert("haha");
            alert($(this).val());
});
```

Since I am still new to coding. It would be really appreciated to help me fix my errors!
Thank yoU!

Comment: Why not just use a `<dataset>` with a standard jQuery polyfil?

Comment: `span` elements don't have a `value` property. That is for `input`, `textarea` and other form elements. You want `this.textContent` which is the equivalent of `$(this).text()`

Comment: Thank you! Yep I shouldn't use .val(). But the javascript :$(document).on("click",".hint",function(){.... does not work. How to solve this problem then?

Comment: You could just use `$(".hint").on("click", function() { ... });` unless the `span`s are created dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately I modified the original code a little bit, and the span is created dynamically. But for this problem, even I use static span, and change it to $(".hint").on("click", function() { ... }); it still does not work. I guess it is because the menu only appears when the input box is on focus. Any ideas to fix that? Thank you for your help and patience! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following declaration to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/UL9q9/.  It'll prevent the menu from being hidden when the menu is hovered even though the input has lost :focus.

```
input:not(:focus) + .hints-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what's happening here is you have the menu set to display when the input field has focus, but attempting to click out of the field loses focus and hides the menu.

Comment: Yep, I think that is the problem! Thanks! Do you have any ideas how I can fix that or any other ways to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Yes. You could capture the focus event of the input box and toggle the menu on. And then hide it when the mouse leaves the menu.

Comment: And DRD's suggestion is probably better.